# using lmer for mixed effects models: which factors are nested vs crossed?

Tags: r, mixed-model

I have estimated home range size for 6 individuals (each having a different ID). The home range of each individual is estimated twice for each month (so there is a different estimate for week 1 and week 2), and for two separate years (year 1 and year 2). Therefore each individual has four estimates corresponding to the following combinations for each month: 1) Week 1, Year 1, 2) Week 1, Year 2, 3) Week 2,Year 1, 4) Week 2, Year 2. I am interested in determining whether there is a significant difference in home range size between months. Would I be incorrect is assuming that ID, Week, and Year are all crossed random effects, or is week nested in year? Below is the line I current have:

```
a <- lmer(Home range size (km2)~ Month +(1|ID)+(1|Year)+(1|Week),
        data= data, REML=FALSE)
```

Comment: if you only have two years, you should probably make year a fixed effect. Then, provided that weeks are uniquely labeled (i.e. not 1,2, 1,2,... but yr1.month1.wk1, yr1.month1.wk2, ...),`rngsize ~ month + year + (1|ID) + (1|week)` should work.